# checkboxlist in asp.net MVC edit view don do postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

so using this example to do a checkboxlist

[checkboxlist in asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217747/checkboxlist-in-asp-net-mvc)

it work fine in my create (for new registre) but not in my edit and can't figure why
 my class:

```
public class cliente
    {
        [Key ,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Nombre")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Descripcion es requerido.")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "El Nombre no puede contener mas de 100 caracteres")]
        public string descripcion {get; set;}


        [DisplayName("Visita")]
        public string visita { get; set; } 


        public Dias DiasVisita { get; set; }

       //more properties..

        [Flags]//<-- Note the Flags attribute
        public enum Dias
        {
            Lunes = 1,
            Martes = 2,
            Miercoles = 4,
            Jueves = 8,
            Viernes = 16,
            Sabado = 32,
            Domingo = 64,
        }
```

My view.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Cliente</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.categoria)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.visita)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.descripcion)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.descripcion, new { style = "width: 300px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.descripcion)
        </div>


      <div class="editor-label">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.visita)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.CheckboxListForEnum("dias", Model.DiasVisita)
    </div>

      <div class="editor-label">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.orden)
    </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.orden)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.orden)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

controller action editar it not enter here when I push the button debugging

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Editar(cliente cliente, string[] dias)
        {
    }
```

how can i know when i push my button where it goes or what it look for? 
the strange thing is that my create is the same as this edit but the create work

Comment: If you run it in firefox with Firebug. If you open the Net tab, where does it try and go when you press the button?

Comment: Did you try Html.BeginForm("ControllerName" , "Editar"), instead of pure Html.BeginForm() if they are on the same area ?

Answer (score 0):

When you push the submit button the controller automatically picks up the post value of the fields you have specified from the form that is submitted.

If you want to debug then put a break point in the controller's action and with see all posted values in the Model object because Model binding is done automatically for you

Comment: my error was that I have to hide my DiasVisita property of my class and is working now

 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DiasVisita)

Answer (score 0):

**How can i know when i push my button where it goes or what it look for?**

1) There are many tools to monitor the network. The must well known are:

1. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/network) - for firefox
2. [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

2) As HatSoft said, you push the button you submit all the fields inside the form tag.

3) If you want to be more specific to define where the post request goes, use the [FormExtensions.BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform.aspx) overloads, in your case, you could use:

```
Html.BeginForm("YourControllerName", "Editar", new {area="YourAreaName"})
```