# get the html Id for a checkboxlist in my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

if I have this html checkbox list code, how in mvc in my post action method how can I get the Id of that checkboxlist? because whith string[] dias i get just the values by example("lunes" "martes" ... etc)

(usgin this example for make my checkboxlist => [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217747/checkboxlist-in-asp-net-mvc))

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Editar(cliente cliente, string[] dias)
        {
         }
```

html

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox" value="Lunes" name="dias">
Lunes
<input id="2" type="checkbox" value="Martes" name="dias">
Martes
<input id="3" type="checkbox" value="Miercoles" name="dias">
Miercoles
<input id="4" type="checkbox" value="Jueves" name="dias">
Jueves
<input id="5" type="checkbox" value="Viernes" name="dias">
Viernes
<input id="6" type="checkbox" value="Sabado" name="dias" checked="checked">
Sabado
<input id="" type="checkbox" value="Domingo" name="dias">
Domingo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the `id`. The `id` attribute is never sent to the server when you submit an form. That's how HTML works. Only the `value` is sent. But checkboxes are a little different because only the `value` attribute of the **checked** checkboxes is sent to the server.

So, simply use the `value` attribute for that purpose:

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox" value="1" name="dias">
Lunes
<input id="2" type="checkbox" value="2" name="dias">
Martes
<input id="3" type="checkbox" value="3" name="dias">
Miercoles
<input id="4" type="checkbox" value="4" name="dias">
Jueves
<input id="5" type="checkbox" value="5" name="dias">
Viernes
<input id="6" type="checkbox" value="6" name="dias" checked="checked">
Sabado
<input id="" type="checkbox" value="" name="dias">
Domingo
```

Now in your `string[] dias` parameter you will get a list of the selected ids. Then if you need to get the corresponding names go ahead and query your data store where they reside given this id.